# Установка полей печати по дефолту

Tags: java, swing

Добрый день. У JEditorPane есть такой метод, как print(). При вызове появляется java-диалог с заданием параметров печати. По дефолту установлены значения для всех полей по 25,4мм. Есть ли возможность установить свои дефолтные значения этих параметров? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться полной версией метода [`print`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#print-java.text.MessageFormat-java.text.MessageFormat-boolean-javax.print.PrintService-javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet-boolean-), ему можно передать список атрибутов для печати.

```
        PrintRequestAttributeSet attrs = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        // размер бумаги
        attrs.add( MediaSizeName.ISO_A4 );
        // размер доступной для печати зоны
        attrs.add( new MediaPrintableArea(
                20, // левый верхний угол в (20мм, 20мм)
                20,
                MediaSize.ISO.A4.getX( Size2DSyntax.MM ) - 40, // размеры
                MediaSize.ISO.A4.getY( Size2DSyntax.MM ) - 40,
                Size2DSyntax.MM
            ) );

        (new JEditorPane()).print(
                null,  // headerFormat
                null,  // footerFormat
                true,  // showPrintDialog
                null,  // printService
                attrs, // attributes
                true   // interactive
            );
```

Атрибут [MediaPrintableArea](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/standard/MediaPrintableArea.html) задает прямоугольную область, доступную для печати. Область задается координатами верхнего левого угла и размерами, в портретной ориентации.

Список атрибутов есть в описании пакета [javax.print.attribute.standard](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/standard/package-summary.html).

Comment: Спасибо большое. Всё получилось.